# cannot connect my springboot project to mysql database launched with docker: CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i cant connect my springboot project to mysql database and i cant find why. Ive done other projects before same way and they connected without problems yesterday. Now, all this proyects, also give same problem.

my springbootapplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectSpringApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3326/springmysqlcompanies?serverTimeZone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Ive mysql-connector-java, spring data JPA dependencies.

My docker mysql database is running on port 3326, name is springmysqlcompanies and has same username and password that i specified in my application.properties

Anyone has some idea what is happening? I dont understand cause now all my mysql projects has exact same problem and i didnt modified anything-yesterday they all runned well. Im a bit frustrated

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the error message please ?

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server

Comment: are you sure your mysql container is up and running, can you check mysql container logs ?

Comment: and make sure mapping ports -p 3326:3326

Comment: runned mysql with docker with following command
docker run -p 3326:3326 --name springmysqlcompanies -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e MYSQL_DATABASE=springmysqlcompanies -d mysql:8.0.23

Comment: yes its up and running, dont have any sense